# Go back to page that needed authentication after successful login

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a web site that has a couple of pages that require a login to view (`deals.aspx` and `settings.aspx`) and the page that the login currently redirects to after a successful login (`my_account.aspx`). How can I set it so that if the login page was called from `deals.aspx` or `settings.aspx` that when it authenticates the user it goes back to the page it called from instead of `my_account.aspx`?

`login.aspx.cs`

```
protected void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string loginUser = user.Text;
    string loginPassword = password.Text;
    bool success = false;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(loginUser);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(loginPassword);

    MySqlConnection conn = Database.getConnection();
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryUsers);
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", loginUser);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", loginPassword);
        cmd.Prepare();

        if (success)
        {
            Session["user"] = user.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("~/my_account.aspx");
        }

    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

`deals.aspx.cs` and `settings.aspx.cs`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["user"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
    }
}
```

and there isn't anything in the `my_account.aspx.cs` page right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a parameter when redirecting to the login page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["user"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx?from=ORIGINGPAGE"); //Set parameter here
    }
}
```

Then, retrieve this parameter in the login page and you will know where you have to come back!

Comment: Can you expound on how to retrieve the parameter in the login's cs page? Or point me to a good post for explaining it?

Comment: To retrieve the from parameter, do this:

string from = Page.Request.QueryString["from"];

Then before you redirect to "my_account.aspx", first check if the variable from is empty, if not, redirect to from instead of to "my_account.aspx"

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Request.UrlReferrer to get the previous page in page load and redirect to it after a successful login.